# Word Count Distribution Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tokenize, word-frequency

Need to do a word distribution count from a dataframe. Anyone know how to fix?

raw data:

```
word
apple pear
pear
best apple pear
```

desired output:

```
word    count
apple   2
pear    3
best    1
```

running this code:

```
rawData = pd.concat([rawData.groupby(rawData.word.str.split().str[0]).sum(),rawData.groupby(rawData.word.str.split().str[-1]).sum()]).reset_index()
```

getting this error:

```
ValueError: cannot insert keyword, already exists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.split` then `explode` each list into one column and finally use `value_counts` to count occurrences of each word:

```
out = df['word'].str.split().explode().value_counts()
print(out)

# Output:
pear     3
apple    2
best     1
Name: word, dtype: int64
```

Step by step:

```
>>> df['word'].str.split()
0          [apple, pear]
1                 [pear]
2    [best, apple, pear]
Name: word, dtype: object

>>> df['word'].str.split().explode()
0    apple
0     pear
1     pear
2     best
2    apple
2     pear
Name: word, dtype: object

>>> df['word'].str.split().explode().value_counts()
pear     3
apple    2
best     1
Name: word, dtype: int64
```

**Update**

To get exactly your expected outcome:

```
>>> df['word'].str.split().explode().value_counts(sort=False) \
              .rename('count').rename_axis('word').reset_index()

    word  count
0  apple      2
1   pear      3
2   best      1
```

**Update 2**

Get value counts by country:

```
data = {'country': [' US', ' US', ' US', ' UK', ' UK', ' UK', ' UK'], 
        'word': ['best pear', 'apple', 'apple pear',
                 'apple', 'apple', 'pear', 'apple pear ']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

out = df.assign(word=df['word'].str.split()) \
        .explode('word').value_counts() \
        .rename('count').reset_index()
print(out)

# Output:
   country   word  count
0       UK  apple      3
1       UK   pear      2
2       US  apple      2
3       US   pear      2
4       US   best      1
```

Comment: Do you want to have a count per country?

Comment: Yes, exactly.                                                                                                                      
data: country word
US best pear
US apple
US apple pear
UK apple
UK apple
UK pear
UK apple pear
desired output:                                                                                                            country word count
US best 1
 apple 2
 pear 1
UK apple 3
 pear 2

Comment: I updated my answer, can you check it please?

Comment: one last item: if the column word had special (non-numeric) characters, how would I remove the special characters?

Comment: You can probably use `df['words'].str.replace('\W', '').str.split()`

Comment: thx. I'm running this but it's removing spaces between words. df= df.replace("[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", '', regex = True). i want to drop the special characters but for bi-grams and it's removing the space between the word.

Comment: `df= df.replace("[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]+", '', regex=True)`?